# Template with forwarding vs function for a callback

Tags: c++

I came across a blog where he was describing the Observer pattern using modern C++.

Basically the subscribe method is

```
template <typename Observer>
void registerObserver(Observer&& observer)
{
  observers_.push_back(std::forward<Observer>(observer));
}

std::vector<std::function<void()>> observers_;
```

But I was wondering why he is not just accepting a std::function as the argument instead:

```
void registerObserver(std::function<void()> observer)
{
  observers_.push_back(observer);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a reason. Although you should be moving observer

Comment: The cost to write template registerObserver is same as yours version. So why limit yourself? If in the future he'll want to change observer type to something else he will not need to modify the registerObserver implementation

Comment: I think the first version will give you the opportunity of moving the observe into `std::function` and ultimately in `std::vector` if it is possible. The second option will always make a copy. `.emplace_back` would be better in this sense, I think.